# Prolog insertion sort

Tags: prolog, sorting

There is a simple Prolog insertion sort alghoritm:

```
sorting([A|B], Sorted) :- sorting(B, SortedTail), insert(A, SortedTail, Sorted).
sorting([], []).

insert(A, [B|C], [B|D]) :- A @> B, !, insert(A, C, D).
insert(A, C, [A|C]).
```

It does well on normal lists:

```
?- sorting([5, 4, 9, 1, 3, 8], X).
X = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9].
```

But I also need to sort sublist of list contains any of them:

```
?- sorting([2, 5, [5, 4, 3], [6, 3], 4, 8], X).
X = [2, 4, 5, 8, [5, 4, 3], [6, 3]].
```

Is what return now. And

```
?- sorting([2, 5, [5, 4, 3], [6, 3], 4, 8], X).
X = [2, 4, 5, 8, [3, 4, 5], [3, 6]].
```

what I need to return. So how can I sort sublist too? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

## I offer this simple solution:

Insert element in the sorted list

```
insert(X, [], [X]):- !.
insert(X, [X1|L1], [X, X1|L1]):- X=<X1, !.
insert(X, [X1|L1], [X1|L]):- insert(X, L1, L).
```

Use principe of insertion sort algorithm

```
insertionSort([], []):- !.
insertionSort([X|L], S):- insertionSort(L, S1), insert(X, S1, S).
```