# How to create an argument that inserts a number in List 1 and returns the result in List 2

Tags: list, numbers, prolog

I want to create a predicate `insert(X,L1,L2)` so that when I insert `X` into the list `L1` it returns the result with `L2`. `L1` is already in ascending order.

For example:

```
?-insert(3,[1,4,9],X).

X=[1,3,4,9]
Yes
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715293/prolog-insertion-sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert(Element,List,NewList)

```
 insert(X ,[],[X]).
```

%If the List is empty add Element in the NewList.

```
 insert(X,[Y|Rest],[X,Y|Rest]):-X@Y,!.
```

%If Element is less than the head(Y) of the List add Element(X) to the head of the NewList and then add the tail of the List

```
 insert(X,[Y|Rest0],[Y|Rest]):-insert(X,Rest0,Rest).
```

%if Element(X) is not less than the Head(Y) of the List then add the Head(Y) to the NewList and 
%recurse again